# Why am I declaring a private variable to then instantiate after?

Tags: c#, instantiation

I'm currently following along with [this](https://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/) course and in lesson 05.1 we create a private variable that takes the created Player class as the data type(?).

```cs
using GameEngine;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserInterface
{
    public partial class DragonlightRPG : Form
    {
        #region Member Variables

        private Player _player;

        #endregion Member Variables

        #region Constructors

        public DragonlightRPG()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Instantiate a new Player class.
            _player = new Player();

            // Assign value(s) to the player object properties.
            _player.CurrentHealth = 100;
            _player.Gold = 25;
            _player.MaximumHealth = 100;
            _player.PlayerExperience = 0;
            _player.PlayerLevel = 1;

            // Get the value(s) of the properties from the _player object, and
            // assign them to the text property of the labels on the form.
            lblExperience.Text = _player.PlayerExperience.ToString();
            lblGold.Text = _player.Gold.ToString();
            lblHitPoints.Text = _player.CurrentHealth.ToString();
            lblLevel.Text = _player.PlayerLevel.ToString();
        }

        #endregion Constructors
    }
}
```

If the private variable `_player` has the Player class set as the data type on line 10, why do we then create a new instance of that class on line 21 and assign it to the already predefined variable _player? Is there any reason why it's done this way? Can I do something like; `Player player = new Player();` while achieving the same result?

Comment: An object is `null` until it is assigned a value. `_player` is `null` until you call `new Player();` You could just do `private Player _player = new Player` there if you wanted to, this is a choice made by the developer. I would probably do the same, since the constructor is for, well, constructing your object, so it makes sense to have the instantiation there along with the instantiation of the class itself. But its entirely subjective. But the `private Player _player` part minimum has to be where it is so other functions in the class can use it. Else it would be gc'd after constructor closes

Comment: Another good example in gaming is when you have that Player Object as `null` is: You may have an instance in the game where a Method allows you to gain a `_player`. You can then create `_player2` when needed and when the Method or Game Action is over, it gets destroyed. Rather than having `Player _player2 = new Player();` with set Hit Points, Gold etc. **all the time**. You may want to have something alter those values based on some dynamic game presence or action. In the grand scheme of things, it's nice to have something you can use whenever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference here is in the *declaration* of a variable versus the *instantiation* of an object that will be assigned to that variable.

In the class definition, the first reference to _player simply establishes a declaration to a variable of the type 'Player' - it does not create an *instance* of a Player object:

```
private Player _player;
```

The 'DragonlightRPG()' method, conversely, *does* perform the instantiation of the object with the 'new Player();' call, assigning the created object to the _player private member:

```
_player = new Player();
```

The former establishes the variable, the latter creates the object to be held in the variable.

You could have instantiated the object earlier;  however, the most general guidance would be to create an object immediately when it is needed, use it, then destroy it. Further, the specifics of any particular use case might dictate that a particular object be created only at certain times, or should be instantiated only when a particular method is called. Those kinds of decisions are often a matter of individual requirements.

Comment: Just to be clear, by assigning to a member variable (as opposed to a method local variable) the lifetime is the same as if you had instantiated on decleration. You don't manually destroy objects in C#, you just let them fall out of scope (and sometimes `Dispose` them if they implement IDisposable).

Comment: There are, however, many times in which it is appropriate or even necessary to separate the two events, as this code shows you *can* do, even if its rather meaningless in the provided code.